# How to add OR Condition Inside XPATH of XSLT Template Match

Tags: templates, xslt, match

I am in with a requirement for selecting two Values of a Field of 2 Nodes of XSLT.

I need to select the Node A1 and A2 by selecting both CAT and DOG.

Input Looks like this.

```
<MAIN>
    <A1>
        <B1>CAT</B1>
        <B2>KITTEN</B2>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <B1>DOG</B1>
        <B2>PUPPY</B2>
    </A2>
    <A3>
        <B1>LION</B1>
        <B2>CUB</B2>
    </A3>
</MAIN>
```

I am using below Expression:

```
    <xsl:template match="MAIN[(A1/B1='CAT') or (A2/B1='DOG')]">
    </xsl:template>
```

This is giving XPATH Expression Error at Runtime.

Also Used below and value was not picked up.

```
   <xsl:template match="MAIN[A1/B1='CAT' or A2/B1='DOG']">
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal but complete sample that causes the error, together with information as to which tool or XSLT processor gives you the error for which line exactly? I don't see anything wrong and at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/948Fn5i your template does not give any error message.

Comment: Don't tell us something gives an error, without telling us what the error is. You might not understand the error message, but the chances are, we will recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

`Or` operator in *XPath* is written as `|` (vertical bar).

To refer to an element containing some text value you should use
a predicate, something like `[text() = '...']`.

So your template can be written as:

```
<xsl:template match="A1/B1[text() = 'CAT'] | A2/B1[text() = 'DOG']"/>
```

Note that in the case of an empty template you don't have to write
any separate closing tag. It is enough to write `<xsl:template .../>`
as I did above.

### Additional remarks

Instead of `text()` you can write `.` a dot.

*XPath* expression `A1[B1 = 'CAT']` is also correct, but its meaning is
different than above. It refers to:

- **whole** `A1` element,
- which has child `B1` element with content *CAT*.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the failure. The 'or' operator is defined in both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 and is used correctly in the example code shown. Furthermore, the substitute code given has a completely different effect: it matches B1 elements rather than the MAIN element.

Comment: Matching the main element in an empty template has little sense. Actually, in the case of matching the output content would be empty. This is why I assumed that the real intent was to "suppress" the matching elements from the output. On the other hand, I should have mentioned this in my answer.